# Bind9 with dyndns refuses to update one zone, works OK on another with the same key

Tags: bind, dynamic-dns, dyndns

I have a Bind9 server (RHEL 8.5) in my lab that was working perfectly fine until a couple of hours ago. Then, it stopped updating one of the 2 zones for which I have setup dynamic DNS.

The `example.com` receives the updates (add and delete records). However, the reverse zone is not working.

The configuration for both files is the following:

```
zone "0.0.10.in-addr.arpa" in {
    type master;
    file "master/10.0.0.zone";
    allow-query { lab; };
    allow-update { key update-key.; };
};

zone "example.com" in {
    type master;
    file "master/example.com.zone";
    allow-query { lab; };
    allow-update { key update-key.; };
};
```

The error message is the following:

```
Jan 26 18:27:50 dnssrv named[890542]: client @0x7f128c048c20 10.1.0.12#49800/key update-key: updating zone 'example.com/IN': update unsuccessful: testsrv.example.com/A: 'rrset exists (value independent)' prerequisite not satisfied (NXRRSET)

Jan 26 18:27:50 dnssrv named[890542]: client @0x7f12a41a3500 10.1.0.12#49802/key update-key: signer "update-key" approved
Jan 26 18:27:50 dnssrv named[890542]: client @0x7f12a41a3500 10.1.0.12#49802/key update-key: updating zone 'example.com/IN': adding an RR at 'testsrv.example.com' A 10.1.0.153

Jan 26 18:27:51 dnssrv named[890542]: client @0x7f1280059890 10.1.0.12#49804/key update-key: update '0.10.IN-ADDR.ARPA/IN' denied
Jan 26 18:27:51 dnssrv named[890542]: client @0x7f128c0410d0 10.1.0.12#49806/key update-key: update '0.10.IN-ADDR.ARPA/IN' denied
```

I used `rndc trace` to increase the log level to 6, but to no avail, I didn't find any more clues about the issue.

I am really in the dark since so far I have tried:

- Delete the dynamic directory and re-create it
- Delete the zone file and restore it from a known working backup
- Re-install named packages
- Create a new TSIG key
- Allow updates without key/network check.

I still get this refused message, so, I am completely in the dark.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to show the update command you used.  `'rrset exists (value independent)'` means you are trying to do an update that is incompatible with the current zone content. For example you have a CNAME on a name, and you try to add a CNAME on same name, without removing previous one, and per DNS rules that would yield an invalid configuration so the request is denied. The problem is not related to the key or anything else, but just the zone content.

Comment: Yes, that was my initial thought. But I was adding an A record for an IP that didn't exist. 
I am suspecting a rogue update at a previous point in time resulted to this error. And since I removed the journal files and "recreated" the zone it was OK. That's the only logical explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I solved the problem by doing:

- Stop named service
- Remove all jnl files
- Recreate the zone file

Still no idea what caused this issue.